# JBOSS EAP 6.4 - URL Rewrite / Redirect

Tags: http, url-rewriting, jboss

I have been refraining from posting here because at times it seems like the easy way out, but I'm close to pulling my hair out now.  In one of my JBOSS EAP 6.4 instances, we have connections like the following coming in on HTTP:

```
server:9990/console
server:9080/application1
server:9085/application2
```

I have my certificates etc all sorted and therefore I want the above to redirect to the following (irrespective of whether the user has entered http or https):

```
https://server:9443/console
https://server:9180/application1
https://server:9185/application2
```

The HTTP ports will not be used once I get this working...hopefully.  Anyways, I have been Googling for hours, and I cannot figure this out.  I have this so far in my standalone-full-ha.xml, under the virtual-server entry:

```
<rewrite pattern="^/(.*)$" substitution="https://server:9443/console" flags="RL">
  <condition test="%{SERVER_PORT}=9990" pattern="on" />
</rewrite>      
<rewrite pattern="^/(.*)$" substitution="https://server:9180/" flags="RL">
  <condition test="%{SERVER_PORT}=9080" pattern="on" />
</rewrite>
<rewrite pattern="^/(.*)$" substitution="https://server:9185/" flags="RL">
  <condition test="%{SERVER_PORT}=9085" pattern="on" />
</rewrite>
```

I am probably missing something obvious here, but I cannot seem to see what it is.  Nothing is happening when the URLs are access, in the sense that they don't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I had still been faffing around with this and come to find out that I can't control the management URLs / how they behave using the web subsystem.

The key issue I had earlier was my own doing, as I spent most of the time trying to work out why the port 9990 to 9443 rewrite was not working, and ignored the fact that the other two were fine.

The web / application rewrites work as I mentioned in the original question :)

Comment: Sorry, I lie, if I try and browse to http with the https port (or vice versa) I get errors in the browser because it doesn't switch to either https or 9180. Modifying the application's web.xml file to specify the security constraints works but this isn't supported by the vendor and therefore I'm not allowed to make such a change.

Comment: @user613114 Apologies, I was doing all this as part of a previous job.  I know that I did manage to sort it out, but I have no idea how and I cannot even check for you.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Try these adapted from solution at [Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in jboss eap 6.4](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274510)

```
<rewrite pattern="^/(console.*)$" substitution="https://server:9443/$1" flags="RL">
  <condition test="%{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
</rewrite>
<rewrite pattern="^/(application1.*)$" substitution="https://server:9180/$1" flags="RL">
  <condition test="%{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
</rewrite>
<rewrite pattern="^/(application2.*)$" substitution="https://server:9185/$1" flags="RL">
  <condition test="%{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score -2):

kindly modify as below.

```
<rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^/context A/(.*resource)" substitution="/context B/resource" flags="R"/>
```

JBoss CLI command:

```
/subsystem=web/virtual-server=default-host/rewrite=jboss:add(pattern="^/$", substitution="/context B/", flags="L,R=302")
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this changes it to HTTPS and changes the port whilst retaining the other parts?